# How to set TortoiseGit default Revert/Reset to HARD

Tags: tortoisegit

I keep forgetting to change the Revert/Reset to HARD (defaults to Mixed or Soft).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now (2.3.4) there is no way to change the default (mixed is also the default on Git cli and I suppose there is the least chance of data loss with this default).